# Is it bad practice to use only one token for a SPA (no applications, only user)?

Tags: authentication, session-management, jwt

Say we have multiple instances of application X deployed on **site1.com, site2.com, site3.com**, etc. And we have a centralized server at **example.com** serving all of these.

All the instances of X are static sites, that is, they do not have a server, and thus, they can't proxy requests to endpoints.

Traditionally, in a same-site situation, HTTPOnly, secure cookies would've been used to store user sessions, but with the (necessary) death of third-party cookies, **we can't do that cross-site.** So recently we have been debating about shifting to storing the session token or JWT in LocalStorage or in a cookie (using Javascript).

We understand the issues with XSS and CSRF involved, but we don't understand how else to make authentication work cross-site. Our application instances are usually "control panels" where users log in to manage their data or other information regarding their organization. They are strictly user <-> server and there is no third-party application involved which might require some access_token.

I have read in a lot of places that storing tokens (JWTs) in LocalStorage is a bad idea. Other places ask you to avoid cookies since they are vulnerable to CSRF. And some places ask you to use id_token and access_token. So where are we supposed to store tokens then?

It's quite confusing, and I seem to be missing something super obvious (or super complicated). Thanks for helping out!

**Related**
This post encouraged me to post this question, but I don't feel like the answer takes into account our cross-site use case:
[OIDC - what is the point of two separate tokens - access and id?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189762/oidc-what-is-the-point-of-two-separate-tokens-access-and-id?newreg=0c211507bce54fdfbc427501e61b80f5)

Comment: g'day - I'm trying to understand your workflow - can you please describe how the user authenticates to the service, and then how the single page application (SPA) integrates your data? *"They are strictly user <-> server and there is no third-party application involved which might require some access_token."* ... from what I can gather of the description, it seems to me that your clients' users go to siteA, which is a dns entry to `siteA.yourservice.com`?

Comment: Hi @brynk, this is the workflow:

(1) User opens site1.com and goes to the login page;
(2) An API call is made to api.example.com to authenticate the user;
(3) The server finds the database mapped against site1.com, retrives the user, validates the password hash and generates a token;
(4) The token is sent back and stored in Localstorage / as a JS cookie;
(5) The token is sent with the request header by the frontend on subsequent requests;

The same server that issues the token also provides the resource, i.e. the authentication, authorization, and resource servers are the same.